# Keeping only N smallest elements with STL (with duplicates)

Tags: c++, stl

The MVCE below attempts to output only the 5 smallest elements in ascending order from a large incoming input stream of random elements (which contains duplicates).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::set<int> s;   //EDIT:  std::multiset is an answer to Q1

    for (int i : {6, 6, 5, 8, 3, 4, 0, 2, 8, 9, 7, 2})  //Billions of elements in reality
    {
        if ( (s.size() < 5) || (i <= *(--s.end())) )  //Insert only if not full or when the element to be inserted is smaller than the greatest one already in the set
        {
            if (s.size() >= 5)  //Limit the number of smallest elements that are kept. In reality ~8000
                s.erase(*(--s.end())); //Erase the largest element

            s.insert(i);
        }
    }

    for (int d: s)
        std::cout << d << " ";  //print the 5 smallest elements in ascending order      

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0 2 3 4
```

The output should be:

```
0 2 2 3 4
```

**Q1**: What must be changed to allow duplicates ?
**Q2**: How can this code be made faster while not wasting GBs of memory for storing all of the input elements? (the code is way too slow now, as it is).

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) _std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of **unique objects** of type Key._ by the other hand: `std::multiset` _Unlike set, **multiple keys** with equivalent values are allowed_ You can see here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a47d30553cf3e96

Comment: @Amadeus: Yes, I know the `std::set` is not the way to go, but this code snippet illustrates the goal better than words.  The `priority_queue is` even worse because its size cannot be limited (it cannot be shrunk), despite allowing duplicates,

Comment: maybe you can elucidated me where my comment fails your expectation

Comment: @Amadeus.  Yes your comment about `std::multiset` is spot on about the first question.  I answered before you supplemented your comment with this suggestion.  I have edited my post to reflect your solution.

Comment: You should not change your question after getting answer. At doing that you invalidated answers that were legitmed at the time you had made your first question. I have downvoted your question

Comment: @Amadeus. Sorry. IT happened so quickly.  Would it be fine if I'd deleted this question and reposted it with the 2nd question only ?

Comment: Probably. Since i can't figure out, where do you get those GB of wasted data, as std::multiset containing 5 elements won't grow that large.

Comment: No, I believe it is enough to change it back to its original objective

Comment: @Amadeus: OK I changed it back.  Please make you comment an answer so I can give you credit for answer to Q1.

Comment: @Radoslaw: I did not write that the cited code wastes GBs of memory.  What I wrote was a forward looking statement - a restriction on some potential solution, e.g. using `priority_queue` to insert all the input elements in it, and `pop` only the 5 smallest.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson -- Storing the smallest 5 elements sounds like a job for a *max-heap* of 5 elements.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Interesting.  I have never used max-heap ...nor multiset for that matter.  Anyway, as the input elements are incoming, the contents of the heap must be searched, to find the correct insertion point,  each time the new element is smaller than the largest element already in the heap. Is this searching faster for the heap or for the multiset ?

Comment: You can utilize the C++ heap functions such as `std::make_heap`, `std::pop_heap`, etc.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson A heap (min-heap, max-heap) is one of those fundamental data structures you need to be familiar with, right up there with stack, queue, linked list, etc. -- it is discussed in great detail in any good data structures textbook.  A multiset -- IMO, it is "different" and has its uses, but is it fundamental?  I don't know, it's a matter of opinion.  It really isn't used that much, to be honest (admittedly I haven't used it to any great extent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like the classical interview question "how to store the smallest N items, without knowledge of the size of the data that will be processed?".

One answer is to use a max-heap of N items, and then adjust the heap (remove the top element, add the new element, heapify) if the subsequent item is less than or equal to the top most item in the heap.

This can be easily done using the C++ library functions [std::make_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), [std::pop_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap), and [std::push_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap).

Here is an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> s; 
    for (int i : {6, 6, 5, 8, 3, 4, 0, 2, 8, 9, 7, 2})
    {
        // add the first 5 elements to the vector
        if (s.size() < 5)
        {
            s.push_back(i);
            if ( s.size() == 5 )
                // make the max-heap of the 5 elements   
                std::make_heap(s.begin(), s.end());
            continue;
        }

        // now check if the next element is smaller than the top of the heap
        if (s.front() >= i)
        {
            // remove the front of the heap by placing it at the end of the vector
            std::pop_heap(s.begin(), s.end());
                   
            // get rid of that item now 
            s.pop_back();

            // add the new item 
            s.push_back(i);

            // heapify
            std::push_heap(s.begin(), s.end());
        }
    }

    // sort the heap    
    std::sort_heap(s.begin(), s.end());

    for (int d : s)
        std::cout << d << " ";  //print the 5 smallest elements in ascending order      

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 2 2 3 4
```

Of course you can make this a function and replace the hard-coded `5` with `N`.

If there are billions of elements, i.e. many more elements than N, the only thing that will be kept in the heap are N elements.

The max-heap is only manipulated if it is detected that the new item satisfies being one of the smallest N elements, and that is easily done by inspecting the top item in the heap and comparing it with the new item that is being processed.

---

If you want to get the 5 largest items, you would build a min-heap instead of a max-heap.  To accomplish this, the only change is to call a functor to change the comparison operator in the heap functions, plus change the test to `>=` instead of `<=`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> s; 
    for (int i : {6, 6, 5, 8, 3, 4, 0, 2, 8, 9, 7, 2})
    {
        // add the first 5 elements to the vector
        if (s.size() < 5)
        {
            s.push_back(i);
            if ( s.size() == 5 )
                // make the min-heap of the 5 elements   
                std::make_heap(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<int>());
            continue;
        }

        // now check if the next element is larger than the top of the heap
        if (s.front() <= i)
        {
            // remove the front of the heap by placing it at the end of the vector
            std::pop_heap(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<int>());
                   
            // get rid of that item now 
            s.pop_back();

            // add the new item 
            s.push_back(i);

            // heapify
            std::push_heap(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<int>());
        }
    }

    // sort the heap    
    std::sort_heap(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<int>());

    for (int d : s)
        std::cout << d << " ";  //print the 5 largest elements in descending order      

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
9 8 8 7 6
```

Comment: This is a neat solution!  Besides the output not being in the ascending order, how does the complexity of heapifying that vector compare to inserting an element into the `multiset` ?

Comment: You can see the complexity on the linked page to `push_heap` (log N comparisons).  So it is very close to O(1) for a 5 elements max heap.  And also, remember that heapify is only called when it is determined that the element needs to be added, and that is an O(1) comparison.

Comment: As to multiset, you probably won't see much of a difference in terms of timings, but remember that multiset takes up more memory than a heap.  If `N` was a million items, then that could tilt your decision to use a heap.  Note that the functions to manipulate the heap are generic.  They are *not* container specific functions.  You could have used a plain-old array of 5 elements in the code instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: I updated the answer to call `sort_heap` at the end.  This now satisfies your requirements of having sorted data.

Comment: // get rid of that item now 
            s.pop_back();

Shouldn't this be pop_front()?

Comment: `std::pop_heap(s.begin(), s.end());` -- That swaps the front item and back item.  Then the back item is removed using `s.pop_back()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this, no need to sort everything. this only sorts until the first 5 elements are on the front of the vector, does not need any additional memory (sort is in-place), vector is fast regarding inserts

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{

    std::vector<int> vec{ 6, 6, 5, 8, 3, 4, 0, 2, 8, 9, 7, 2 };
    int numElements = 5;

    std::partial_sort(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + numElements, vec.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << vec[i]  << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

if you do not want to store all inputs, it depends a bit on how you read the input, but the solution will be a bit different. For example read chunks, take smallest 5 of each chunck and in the end just execute once more on the combined "smallest 5" of each chunk.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that vector use as much memory as all the input elements combined ?  In my application, there are billions of them.

Answer (score 0):

Q2 ans: Go trought first N elements of the multiset(i am not sure if it is sorted highest to lowest or lowest to highest, so adjust that), and `push_back()`  them to a `std::vector`.