# What's the most efficient algo for finding the smallest/largest K elements in an unsorted array?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an unsorted vector of N elements and would like to find the K lowest or largest elements. K is expected to be K << N way smaller than N but the algo should be robust to be efficient also for larger values of K e.g. 50-80% of N.

Thinking along the lines of reusing Quicksort would mean using exactly the Kth smallest/largest element as pivot to partition. But finding the Kth smallest/largest value is already computing the solution to the OP.

Here is the partition bit of Quicksort:

```
template<typename T>
int partition(std::vector<T>& arr, int low, int high, T pivot) {
    int i = (low - 1); 

    for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; ++j) {
        if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            std::swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
        }
    }
    std::swap(arr[i + 1], arr[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}
```

If I knew what the `pivot` value would be corresponding to the Kth smallest/largest then I can use the partition above to solve my OP.

Comment: Use a min-heap / max-heap of N elements.

Comment: Is the vector sorted?

Comment: [Quick select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) perhaps?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but you should first insert all of the item into min/max heap that takes O(NLogN), No?

Comment: Using a min-heap/max heap of `K` elements is enough, no need of size of `N`

Comment: I should have said a min or max heap of `K` elements.  The size of `N` is irrelevant.  Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507928/keeping-only-n-smallest-elements-with-stl-with-duplicates/56508520#56508520) is of any help?

Comment: Min/max heap works in O(n log k), not a big difference from sorting the array in O(n log n) for a bigger k tbh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Partial_sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) will put the least (greatest) K elements in the front of a container, and sort them.  Call it like

```
std::partial_sort(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + K, arr.end());
std::partial_sort(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + K, arr.end(), std::greater<>());
```

It will run about N log K time

Answer (score 5):

The standard library [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) algorithm does what you want in O(n) complexity. Given the call:

```
std::nth_element(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + K, arr.end());
```

The Kth element is the element that would occur if the whole range was sorted. Elements before the Kth will all be less than or equal to the Kth element.

By default the algorithm uses the less-than operator. If you want the largest K elements you can use a different compare function, such as:

```
std::nth_element(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + K, arr.end(), std::greater<>{});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at median of medians algorithm (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians). It takes O(n) time and does exactly that. It's one of the most efficient algorithms if not the best one.