# finding top 10 elements in the hash table which contains 250,000 integer elements in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, hashtable

i want to find top 10 elements int the hash table. The hash table contains 250000 elements and these elements are only integer values. I dont want to sort the whole table. When i find the top 10 elements it is enough for me the rest is not important. What is the FASTEST(RUNTİME) way to do it? maybe heap sort? C++

Comment: Hashtables contain key-value pairs, so the question as it stands makes little sense. It wouls also be useful if you mention the specific programming language you use to tackle this.

Comment: I'm using C++ language

Comment: You can't know you have the top 10 elements if you did not check the whole table. You don't have to sort everything though to get them. Hash is irrelevant here.

Comment: "Get the top K items" is a classical problem that is usually solved by using a min-heap of K items.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507928/keeping-only-n-smallest-elements-with-stl-with-duplicates/56508520#56508520).  Adapt that answer to find the top 10 items (build a min-heap instead of a max-heap, and switch the comparison).  Basically change 3 lines of code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie is this the fastest way? because I want the fastest way to find the top 10

Comment: @GarpayGavs -- What way do you propose?  You have to go through the entire data, regardless.  The hard part is getting the top 10 and keeping track of it while iterating.  Concentrate on the latter (keeping track of the top 10), and not the former (how to iterate a map).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie hmmm so you guys are saying that it will be linear in best case scenario

Comment: Let's say that the top 10 items occur in the last 10 entries.  How would you ever get to them if you don't go through all the data?

Comment: Can do linear in worst case by iterating over the entire collection once. Counting sort and such would also work

Comment: @GarpayGavs -- Also, what if you add 1000 items to the table.  Now you want to get the top 10 items after you already got the top 10 items from the previous state of the map.  Are you going to start the search all over again, or use the already-built min-heap and just check those 1000 items?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie in that case, I would check all over again but there is a txt file which is given and there is a fixed number of elements. So I thought at first, I will hash them all (250000 elements) then there won't be more elements to add

Comment: @GarpayGavs --*in that case, I would check all over again* - My point is that you don't check all over again.  You just pick up where you left off if you keep the top N items in a heap data structure.  The second thing is that you didn't show us anything about your hash table.  If you're using `std::unordered_map`, then the solution is relatively straightforward using a min-heap.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes sir I am using an unordered map. Actually, I haven't formed a hashtable yet :D if you have a suggestion to store them you are really welcome :D these I mentioned are just blueprints for my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that the integers are in a collection you can iterate over.

Imagine you need to find the **single** max element - you can iterate over the collection once keeping track of the largest element you have seen so far.

Now modify the above approach for the top two elements you have seen so far.

...

Now modify the above approach for the top ten elements you have seen so far.

This "algorithm" has linear complexity which is as good as it gets.
There are other ways of achieving linear time - all better then what you will get from Heapsort.

Comment: The big step in the proposed sequence of modifications is to go from *the* largest to the top *two* largest; increasing the *two* to other counts is then straight forward.