# Algorithm to store elements of a list in a random order in a key/value store without a defined order, but retrieve max/min value

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, hashmap, key-value

While executing the application in question (a blockchain node, but regardless), every new block that comes over time has a number associated with it; The number is called "ChainWork"; it's a 256-bit number with a custom comparison function (not native to C++).

The ChainWork associated with new blocks can theoretically have any value compared to the previous blocks' values. Because there are way too many blocks, assuming we don't want to store all the blocks (or even their ChainWork) in memory, we have to store them in a persistent storage.

The only storage available is a key/value store that does not guarantee that these numbers are stored in order. There is not even a pre-defined storage order (think of it as a hash map).

**The problem: We need to store these numbers in that persistent storage, but retrieve only the maximum value at will**

**The question**: Is there a way or algorithm that can make it possible to get the maximum value of the ChainWork values available at any point in time (and some associated information with them), provided that we can store any extra information required to help in retrieving the maximum value from the unsorted container? In other word, is there a way to reasonably sacrifice storage to get better complexity for this problem, instead of having to loop over all the ChainWork values, with O(N)?

If you require any additional information, please go ahead and ask.

EDIT: Keeping track of the max does not work because the max can be removed at times, so a re-loop over all the values would be required. I forgot to mention this point, but it came up in the comments. Apologies.

Comment: Umm... Keep track of the maximum value every time a key/value pair gets added to the container, separately?

Comment: IMO the question is for https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Unfortunately, that doesn't work. There's an operation that can remove blocks such that their ChainWork maximum isn't maximum anymore, so a new loop has to be run all over the available values, which is O(N) again.

Comment: Well, you see, that just goes to show that you'll have to figure something out on your own, because only you know all your full requirements. Even if I make a few more suggestions, it is still likely that the response would be "oh, because of <X> it won't work", so this won't be productive, or useful.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Or... I can update the question because I forgot that point.

Comment: I think the best way is simply (indirectly) order them. (or something like heap)

Comment: @appleapple -- I was thinking the same thing, some sort of heap.  With the heap, you can limit not just the maximum value, but the `N` largest values, no matter how many items that come in.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist *Keeping track of the max does not work because the max can be removed at times, so a re-loop over all the values would be required.* -- To add to the previous comment, it looks like you've overlooked the basic [max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) data structure.  Also at the link is the following sentence:  -- *A heap is a useful data structure when it is necessary to repeatedly remove the object with the highest (or lowest) priority,* -- Sound familiar?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'll have to think if a heap helps in solving the problem. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist -- Also, if the heap sounds like something that can be used, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507928/keeping-only-n-smallest-elements-with-stl-with-duplicates/56508520#56508520).  The only change is that you would want to build a min-heap (add a lambda to the C++ standard heap functions), and flip the test around to see if the incoming item is smaller than the one on the top of the heap.

Comment: Just curious, have you looked at something like a BTree?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Nevertheless, the explanation of the answer at that link still remains valid -- if the number of items is coming in from an unlimited stream of values  and you want to store the N smallest/largest, the heap is the standard way to go.  Much better than storing a vector of thousands (maybe millions) of items, and having to fix it up just because the max value has changed.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I'm not sure how to use a BTree to solve this problem. I still have to think about the heap suggested by PaulMcKenzie. But it's 11 PM here and my brain is fried. I'll definitely post an answer if I find it. I really appreciate your efforts, guys.

Comment: The operation done on the data structure are not specified. I guess you can insert/delete the items and know the this of the container as well as retrieve the value associated to a key. One can prove that if the comparison operator is the only way to know the max, then the *optimal* complexity for the deletion is `O(log n)`. Heaps and binary trees could be used to do so.