# Storage for top N values

Tags: c++, std

Is there something in Standard C++ library for keeping top N values to avoid the reinvention of the wheel in the following way?

Fully functional [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/erMcEcq1x).

The code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class TopNStorage {
    std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, std::greater<T>> counts;
    size_t n;
public: 
    TopNStorage(size_t n) : n(n) {  }

    void add(T value) {
        if (counts.size() >= n) {
            if (value > counts.top()) {
                counts.pop();
                counts.push(value);
            }
        }
        else {
            counts.push(value);
        }
    }

    auto get_values() const { 
        std::vector<T> sorted_collocations_counts(counts.size());

        std::copy(&(counts.top()), &(counts.top()) + counts.size(), sorted_collocations_counts.begin());
        std::sort(sorted_collocations_counts.begin(), sorted_collocations_counts.end());

        return sorted_collocations_counts;
    }
};

int main() {
    TopNStorage<int> storage(3);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
        storage.add(i);
    }

    for (auto value : storage.get_values()) {
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }
}
```

**Motivation**

1. Don’t want to reinvent the wheel in case there is something ready (should be, too common task).
2. Too much code for such simple and common task.
3. The implementation is not yet complete, a lot of work to be done to make it generic.

**Reservations**

1. The *N* value could be large, so I don’t want the value to be added and then smallest removed if necessary; the code will be shorter, but this could cause unnecessary calculations and memory allocations. The problem is that priority_queue uses binary heap and `std::vector` as underlying implementation. (a) Adding unnecessary values will lead to excessive heap recalculation which could take time on large N and (b) In case my "extra" value to be deleted, exceeds the size of the allocated vector, it will lead to reallocation and excessive vector content copy. In case N is big enough, this hits. I don't see an **easy** straightforward way to reserve priority_queue capacity (except writing my own memory allocator). If you have the idea how to improve this code, keeping current order of actions, please, step in.
2. Don’t pay much attention to *get_values* method, it provided for demo purposes only.

**Note**

The question is different from the linked [Keeping only N smallest elements with STL (with duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507928/keeping-only-n-smallest-elements-with-stl-with-duplicates) question, since it considers different task. My question is about "keeping it alive when new elements come" and that question is about just extracting elements for once given sequence. Since my question was closed based on that one, I am providing these explanations. Questions address different tasks and different aspects (see my **Reservations**) section. This is wording difficulty with word "keeping" which led to this confusion, so I renamed my question.

Comment: Unrelated: is `greatest-n-per-group` really a necessary tag?

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507928/keeping-only-n-smallest-elements-with-stl-with-duplicates/56508520#56508520).  *Too much code for the simple task.* -- Why is it too much code?  The heap data structure is the classical way to accomplish storing the top (or bottom) N items.

Comment: @user4581301, removed. Interesting thing is that this tag comes when you choose the **top-n** tag. Seems to be a SO bug. Try yourself.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, updated my statement to "Too much code for such simple and common task"; with this I mean that such simple and common task should have more simple way to be solved. I expect to have standard data structure or algorithm in standard library for this. Not a thing that every developer should reinvent from scratch.

Comment: It seems that a `std::multiset` will reduce the above to about three lines of code for `add()` (consisting of an insert and exactly one `if` statement without any `else`), and one line of code for `get_values()`.

Comment: *with this I mean that such simple and common task should have more simple way to be solved* -- Well, binary trees, or even n-ary trees are not in the standard library, and they are common also.  I would say that the case for trees is "worse", since you have to code everything from scratch.  At least with getting the top/bottom N items, you have the heap functions (and priority-queue class) as helpers.

Comment: I also do not see a real issue with your approach. You wrap the "difficult" part in a class. Add unit tests and from then on you have "simple use". If later you find you have performance issues or find a "better" implementation, refactor and run your tests again. The standard library is a set of building block (and doesn't have solutions for everytying). And ofcourse you asking the question here isn't a bad thing either sometimes the standard library does contain something you didn't think of before.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, keeping aside for a moment performance concerns, let me double check that code which you have in mind comply my requirement in *Reservations*: "*The add method will be called very often, so I don’t want the value to be added and then smallest removed if necessary; the code will be shorter, but this could cause unnecessary memory allocations.*". Can you really implement this with three lines without `else`, keeping meeting requirement? I can't see such a solution so far; if you are sure, I'll try myself.

Comment: Sam's Last Theorem ;-)

Comment: I should have been more clear, Damir. I wasn't challenging your use of the tag; `greatest-n-per-group` doesn't seem to be a useful tag *at all*.

Comment: @user4581301, It seems you got me wrong. Let me reword. I decided to use the `top-n` tag which seems to be reasonable here and put it, but SO automatically replaced it with `greatest-n-per-group` while saving. I never aimed to use the  `greatest-n-per-group` and I see `top-n` reasonable, shouldn't I? It seems to be SO defect with auto replacing `top-n` tag with  `greatest-n-per-group` tag on saving.

Comment: If you just want to output in the opposite order, just use `std::sort` with `.rbegin()` and `.rend()`

Comment: Use a priority queue for this. Add a value, and delete the lowest if its size is over N. Three lines of code including the declaration. And no memory reallocation unless they’re objects.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, sorry, I missed your point. Why should I "want" it?

Comment: @user207421, that's exactly what I use (see the code). The problem is that priority_queue uses `std::vector` as underlying implementation. In case my "extra" value to be deleted, exceeds the size of the allocated vector, it will lead to reallocation and excessive vector content copy. In case N is big enough, this hits. I don't see an **easy** straightforward way to reserve priority_queue capacity. Sorry, my initial wording was a little bit misleading; updated the question to make this more explicit.

Comment: Isn't this `std::partial_sort`?

Comment: @DamirTenishev It was unclear what you meant in "Keeping top N values". By using `std::greater<T>` you are already "Keeping top N values" but your output is in ascending order. My point being if you want access in descending value in your output loop, just reverse the order using reverse iterators. (e.g. `5`, `4`, `3` in your code shown) -- as answered in your other question with `std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>`. [Is there a syntax to avoid passing duplicated depended types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77929716/3422102)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thank you, I got the point. I missed this since almost immediately reworked to the [version with comparison predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77929716/is-there-a-syntax-to-avoid-passing-duplicated-depended-types) which solves this naturally. Anyway, thank you for reminding about the hint if reverse would be needed there.

Comment: @user207421, one more important thing than very rare memory reallocation is redundant heap recalculation with this "element added to be removed". On large N this hits.

Comment: @RaymondChen, thank you for the pinpoint, could help in some cases. At the same time taking into account that operations with `std::priority_queue` are O(logN) while operations with `std::partial_sort` is O(Nlog(N)), I would stay here with the priority_queue.

Comment: @DamirTenishev Operations with `std::priority_queue` are O(log N), but you need to do N of them, so the total is O(N log N) which is the same as `std::partial_sort`. (Spoiler alert: `std::partial_sort` is exactly the `priority_queue` algorithm.)

Comment: Or `O(M*log N)`, when using two variables to describe the top `N` of `M` elements.

Comment: @RaymondChen, on the spoiler alert, I suspected this, but can't confirm at least with VS 2022 implementation; at least it doesn't call std::partial_sort directly, as I can see from the sources. If you see otherwise, please share. On the complexity, I tend to agree, they should be similar, although the coefficients may which could lead to some deviations. Anyway, thanks, for now I will consider them equal in terms of performance.

Comment: @Sebastian, sure, but for the case of keeping top N without allocating extra space, M is equal N, so no need to two variables when it collapses to trend in O-notation.

Comment: You didn't define N and M in the question. Is your concern that "std::partial_sort algorithms are intended to be used for small constant numbers of [first, middle) selected elements." or that a small selection means you're not getting the full benefit of heapify being O(M)?

Comment: @KennyOstrom, the `N` is defined in the name of the question and in the name of the class and in the variable. So, it is well-defined. The `M` introduced by *Sebastian* above as the number of the elements to be chosen from. So, both are well-defined. My point is that for TopNStorage I always will keep only N elements to be sorted and never will have more. See the code in the question. So, as *Sebastian* introduced `M` it is equal **in this task** to `N`. I don't have any concern, I just answered to *Sebastian* that such a detail in **this task** is excessive.

Comment: I have an answer ready using nth_element, if I have the right idea. Ah but it was closed as I typed this. I'm pretty sure you want nth_element, and then just erase the rest.

Comment: @KennyOstrom, I am not sure how `std::nth_element` could help here, but it seems that all these algorithms like `std::nth_element`, `std::partial_sort`, etc. are from the same family and with different variations could be used here. The question is, if this could improve the code.

Comment: In the example code in the question, `N=3`, `M=5`. So `O(N*log N)` would generally underestimate (except if one sets `N` to `M`). Yes, I introduced `M` in the comment above and could have better described this: In the example it effectively is the number of calls to `storage.add()`, i.e. the size of the input, whereas `N` is the size of the output (selecting the largest `N`).

Comment: @Sebastian, now I got your idea; with `M` you mean amount of values additions. I agree, you are correct. Thank you for the explanation. The problem that in this case the complexity with `std::partial_sort` will be O(M*N*log(N)), because we gave to call `std::partial_sort` for 'M' times and this algorithm itself has complexity O(N*log(N)). Am I wrong?

Comment: @KennyOstrom, I edited the question to explain the difference between the linked and my questions and sent to reopening; feel free to vote for reopen.

Comment: @DamirTenishev You are right, if it cannot make use of the previous partial_sort. However, with a _manual_ priority queue one should get `O(M*log N)`.

Comment: @Sebastian, well this comes to deep waters with this `if`. It is nothing said that in all cases partial_sort could benefit from its previous run; here we need to go deep into algorithm and check this. Let me take this as granted in this particular topic. So, could switching to `std::partial_sort` improve the existing code keeping or improving its performance, taking into account reservations from my original question?

Comment: @DamirTenishev I would strongly assume, with no further specification or analysis about a specific library implementation, that `std::partial_sort` has not the same performance as a solution with manual `std::priority_queue`. Perhaps that could be even proven by minimum numbers of necessary comparisons. In the quite possible worst case you get the additional factor of `N` in the computational complexity. That `N` could for some tasks be a small number and assumed to be a constant, but then it would not have made sense to define here the complexity in terms of `N` in the first place.

Comment: As `std::priority_queue` does not offer iterators (?): Is the copy in `get_values` allowed? Otherwise one would need repeated `pop`s or the raw heap functions from the std library (starting with `std::make_heap`) to access the elements.

Comment: @Sebastian, well it is hard to say what is allowed and what is not. Of course, this is a hack based on knowledge of implementation, but is is [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) that "*The container must satisfy the requirements of SequenceContainer, and its iterators must satisfy the requirements of LegacyRandomAccessIterator.* (The standard containers std::vector (including std::vector<bool>) and std::deque satisfy these requirements. )". So, yes, this is safe and allowed hack. Also, have you paid attention to my second *Reservation* in the question?