# Is there a syntax to avoid passing duplicated depended types?

Tags: c++

If I want to make class TopNStorage parametrizable with comparison predicate, I have to do something like:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename Pred = std::greater<T>>
class TopNStorage {
    std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, Pred> counts;
    size_t n;
public: 
    TopNStorage(size_t n) : n(n) {  }

    void add(T value) {
        if (counts.size() >= n) {
            if (Pred()(value, counts.top())) {
                counts.pop();
                counts.push(value);
            }
        }
        else {
            counts.push(value);
        }
    }

    auto get_values() const { 
        std::vector<T> sorted_collocations_counts(counts.size());

        std::copy(&(counts.top()), &(counts.top()) + counts.size(), sorted_collocations_counts.begin());
        std::sort(sorted_collocations_counts.begin(), sorted_collocations_counts.end(),Compare());

        return sorted_collocations_counts;
    }
};

int main() {
    TopNStorage<int,std::less<int>> storage(3);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
        storage.add(i);
    }

    for (auto value : storage.get_values()) {
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }
}
```

Although, this is totally fine, the `int` type in `std::less<int>` seems to be redundant in such cases and I’d like to tell the compiler to take it from `typename T` of the class, but I don’t know if I can parametrize the template with another template.
Is there a way to make client code look like:

```cpp
TopNStorage<int,std::less> storage(3);
```

**Motivation**

I don’t like duplication and want to avoid situations when one type could be changes without changing the other (when it comes to more complicated types and code).

**Background**

Based on the question [Keeping top N values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77929558/keeping-top-n-values).

Comment: You can use a template template parameter, but I wouldn't recommend it, because the comparator may not be a template or may not depent on `T` after all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::less` defaults to and is specialized for `void` and that specialization has a comparison operator in the form of

```
template< class T, class U >
constexpr auto operator()( T&& lhs, U&& rhs ) const
    -> decltype(std::forward<T>(lhs) < std::forward<U>(rhs));
```

allowing it to compare any two types as long as there is an underlying `operator <` for them.

You can use this specialization instead of specifying the type like

```
TopNStorage<int,std::less<>> storage(3);
```

which you can see working in this [live example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91f40766660fdd98).

Comment: Nice example, though why the entire first block of headers was included and why you linked against `-lpthread` is a bit curious... Suspect a generic "cover-all" example template (go-by) used with corresponding compile string `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah, that's just a template I add code to online for examples and to quick check error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Since c++14 you can use `std::less<>` and the parameter types will be deduced when the operator is invoked: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less

You can therefore just use:

```
TopNStorage<int,std::less<>> storage(3);
```